# assigning label value to zero if the output is null from the sql query

Tags: c#

i am a newbie to c# 
i am working on winform c#. and i have a query which result in the sum of the column values.
the sum is set to label.text for visibility and the default value is 0 i.e zero my code is

```
    string interoo = "select sum(charge) from table2 
where datepart(mm,given_schedule)= @yourMonthSelected and 
datepart(yy,given_schedule)= @yourYearSelected";
```

the problem is when there is no search result means the output is nothing then the turnover.text is set to null means in the winform it is not visible the text is blanlk i think it returns the dbnull values but how to set it 0 if no search result is found. if search result is found then it will be same but if it is blank then i dont want it to be blank it should be 0. can it be possible?

Comment: Aside: You are missing the "@" in your `AddWithValue` parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various things you can change. For example your query could force ZERO using [**ISNULL** (you can read more here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and you don't need to do `while` if only one item is being returned:

```
string interoo = "SELECT ISNULL(SUM(charge), 0) FROM table2 WHERE datepart(mm,given_schedule)= @yourMonthSelected AND datepart(yy,given_schedule)= @yourYearSelected";

SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(interoo, conn);
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("yourMonthSelected", comboBox1.Text);
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("yourYearSelected", comboBox2.Text);
SqlDataReader rdrr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdrr.Read())
{
    turnover.Text = rdrr[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: ISNULL(SUM(charge), 0) sir you answer works. but can you explain me something what is this isnull means how does it works? it is a sql function and???

Comment: Yes, ISNULL is a SQL method that check if a value is NULL and if so replaces with another value, in this example 0. You could make it return -1 or anything else that would assist. This is useful as your SQL statements become more complex. I've added link to my answer.

Comment: thank you sir for explaining  thank you very much and i dont know about my scenario can you explain why my null value is coming after sorting there is no records then adding that record will lead to 0 not null beacause any adding will lead to last 0 it will never return null so in my case why it is returning null?

Comment: If there are no records that match your WHERE statement then the result will be NULL. This is the defined behaviour for SUM. If you have no records then if SUM returned 0 (zero) it would be misleading as that would suggest there are records.

Comment: yess sir i got what you told and sir here in my case replacing while to if is resulting the same values is there any diffrence between if and while in my case?

Comment: There is no difference. If you have one record then the IF will execute once and WHILE will execute once. Say you had 5 records then IF would still only ever execute once and WHILE would execute 5 times. Because you are expecting only one record it is clearer and shows your intent to only ever get one and use IF. That way other developers would know that code will only read the first record. WHILE may make them re-read the code to see why you think there might be multiple records.

Comment: oh. i got thank you sir for explaning and sir can you tell me what is the diffrence between datepart function and CONVERT function of sqlserver
since out topic but i am searching on google but still my doubt is not clearing can you please help me

Answer (score -1):

change ur code like ...

```
if(rdrr.Read())
{
     turnover.Text = rdrr[0].ToString();
}
else 
{
    turnover.text = "0";
}
```

...just try this and let me know further....

Comment: rajesh bhai it is not. same blank output

Comment: oh ok...be sure that the background color and fore color of the label are not same....also label visible = true.

Comment: yes sir it is same but see the answer by the another person then you will get what is the problem in real